# Search pattern (Regex) python

Tags: python, regex

I downloaded this tool (http://www3.telus.net/pfrank/) to rename thousands of file names (that I inherited) that has bunch of illegal characters. I am trying to find ... in any where in the file name and replace it with nothing.

I tried [...] but it only removes from the end of file name. Any suggestion ?

Comment: use `\.+` instead of `[...]`. If you are looking for specifically 3 dots, then `\.{3}`

Comment: \.+ removes ... from very end and also removes . from the extension. \.{3} removes ... from very end and keeps the . with extension. However, none of the removes ... from beginning or middle of the file name.

Comment: @Kash: Can you reply like vorticity did so i can pick your answer as correct answer. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\.+` instead of `[...]`.
If you are looking for specifically 3 dots, then `\.{3}`

Answer (score 0):

As Kash said, use `\.{3}` rather than `[...]`.  The problem is that the period is a special character in regular expressions.  It means "any character".  So, in order to represent a literal period, you much escape it with the backslash.  `\.{3}` looks for any occurances of exactly three periods in a row.  `\.+` looks for any occurrence of one or more periods in a row (careful, will look for single periods).  `\.\.+` will find all instances of two or more periods in a row, which I expect is what you're looking for.